# Crop a sliding div

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, less

I'm trying to setup a horizontally sliding div for a menu, there is a left DIV that is always visible, and a sliding DIV that scrolls out horizontally when the menu is activated. My html looks like this.

```
<div id="app-menu">
  <div id="menu_left">
    <img src="menu_left.png" />
  </div>
  <div id="menu_slider" class="menu-content">
    <img src="menu_1.png" />
    <img src="menu_2.png" />
    <img src="menu_3.png" />
  </div>
</div>
```

and the slider is animated using some CSS as below

```
    .menu-content {
        position: fixed;
        height: 175px;
        left: -606px;
        top: 35px;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        overflow-y: hidden;
        transition: ease-in-out 400ms left;
    }

    .menu-content-opened {
        left: 125px;
        transition: ease-in-out 600ms left;
    }
```

the menu_slider DIV class is toggled between menu-content & menu-content-opened in a click event on the menu_left DIV. This all works fine.

But my menu_left DIV contains an image menu_left.png with an alpha channel & some transparent areas. When my menu_slider div closes behind menu_left DIV by sliding in to the left, I can see the content of menu_slider DIV behind the menu_left DIV.

What I'd like to do is have the menu_slider DIV slide into the left, but not be visible behind the menu_left DIV, i.e. crop it somehow. I could fill in the transparent areas of the PNG with the page background color, but I'd rather not. I'm using Angular 6, Typescript & .less style files.

Any ideas please ?

Answer (score 0):

You can animate `max-width` instead of animating `left`. I can't think of a better way, because overlapping layers with transparency will always mix together.

Here is a working example:

```js
 const menuDiv = document.getElementById('menu_left');
   menuDiv.addEventListener('click', () => {
     let slider = document.getElementById('menu_slider');
      slider.classList.add('menu-content-opened');
      console.log('clicked');
    });
```

```css
    .menu-content {
        position: fixed;
        height: 175px;
        left: 120px;
        max-width: 0;
        /* left: -606px; */
        top: 35px;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        overflow-y: hidden;
        transition: all ease-in-out 400ms;
    }

    .menu-content-opened {
        max-width: 600px;
    }
    #menu_left {
      background: gray;
      width: 100px;
    }
```

```html
<div id="app-menu">
  <div id="menu_left">
    <img src="https://pngimage.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/png-transparent-background-2.png" alt="MENU LEFT"/>
  </div>
  <div id="menu_slider" class="menu-content">
    <img src="menu_1.png" alt="menu 1" />
    <img src="menu_2.png" alt="menu 2"/>
    <img src="menu_3.png" alt="menu 3"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've tried that, as the width increases the menu 1, menu 2 & menu 3 are stacked vertically & then become horizontal as the width increases. I want the menu images to always be horizontal as they appear.

Comment: @daveD Add to css: `.menu-content img { display: block; }` so that any `img` element will take all available width space in that class.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to change the `display` of the div with the id #menu_slider on click events. You would need to "toggle" the css code from `{display: none;}` to `{display: block;}` and vice versa.